# Generic and specific functions to get real and imaginary parts of complex variables

Tags: fortran

In Fortran, I always work with double precision, so I have been using specific functions like `dble` and `dimag` to get real and imaginary parts of complex variables. However, for other functions like `sin`, I no longer use `dsin` because the former returns a value of proper kind (i.e., `sin` is a generic function). The same seems to hold for complex variables. So my question is:

1) What are the most recommended generic functions for getting real and imaginary parts?

-- It seems that `real(z)`, `aimag(z)`, and `conjg(z)` return a proper kind always (via experiments with gfortran), i.e., if `z` is double precision, those functions return double precision. Is this guaranteed? Also, is the behavior dependent on the standard used by the compiler? (i.e., Fortran 77 vs 90 or later, particularly for `real(z)`?)

2) If I (nevertheless) want to use specific functions that receives only double precision arguments and always return double precision values, what are the specific functions?

-- I have been using `dble(z)` and `dreal(z)`, `dimag(z)`, `dconjg(z)` up to now, but some web pages say that they are vendor extensions (though commonly supported by many compilers).

I have read various pages but the information is rather confusing (i.e., it is not very clear what is the "standard" way), so I would appreciate any advice on the choice of such functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As background, what do we mean by kinds of real and complex variables?  Of course, you know what is meant by the kind of a real object.

A complex object consists of a real and an imaginary part.  If a complex object has a given kind then each component is a real of kind corresponding to the kind of the complex object.

That's a long way of saying, if

```
complex(kind=k) z
```

then `KIND(z%re)` and `KIND(z%im)` both evaluate to `k` (using the complex part designators introduced by Fortran 2008 for clarity).

Now, the `real` intrinsic generic takes a complex expression and returns its real component.  It does so subject to the following F2008 rule (13.7.138), where `A` is the argument:

> If A is of type complex and KIND is not present, the kind type parameter is the kind type parameter of A.

So, yes: in current Fortran `real` without a requested kind will always give you a real of kind that of the complex's real component.  Whether that's double precision or otherwise.

Similarly, `aimag` returns a real (corresponding to the imaginary part) of kind that of the complex number.  Unlike `real`, `aimag` doesn't accept a `kind=` argument controlling the result kind.

Things are different for Fortran 77: there was no similar concept of kind, and just one `complex`.

`dble` is a standard intrinsic.  Although this always returns a double precision it is still generic and will accept any numeric.  `dble(a)` is the same as `real(a,kind(0d0))`, whatever the type of `a`.  There is no (standard) specific.

`dreal`, `dimag` and `dconjg` are not standard intrinsics.

I suppose one could create specific wrappers around `real` if one cared greatly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations. It is my long-standing question (though no problem in practical use). I did not know that this behavior of real(z) is F2008, but does this mean that for compilers not conforming to F2008 (or with such F08 option), is there possibility that it behaves differently (in the worst case, as in F77 and returns single precision)?

Comment: Also, another question is: does the last part of the above answer mean that, there are essentially no "standard" specific functions for "double precision -> double preicision" in the standard(s) (so it is unavoidable to use non-standard ones if one wants to use specific functions for some reason)?

Comment: In F77 `real` always returned default real ("single precision"), but returning the kind given by the `kind=` or that of the complex argument came about in F90.  Again, though, F77 had only the one kind of complex, corresponding to default real, so that's no problem.

Comment: There are no standard _intrinsics_, but of course one could create a non-intrinsic rather than relying on a non-standard intrinsic.

Comment: I see... I think most of my questions above are now clear (and I agree that we can write custom functions based on the standard ones, if necessary). Thanks very much!

Comment: I am not sure that "always use double" makes sense. There are a few compelling reasons to use single precision if one does not need double precision. And less common is something like (ifort) REAL(KIND=16). There is always UNION/MAP that could be used in your own function to return the real and imaginary components, which is likely what is happening under the hood.

Comment: @Holmz, is that a comment on a specific point in my answer?  I certainly agree that `double precision` isn't the only real kind that is desirable: if this answer reads as suggesting that I need to change it.

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading sentences; I guess @Holmz refers to my question, because it starts with "I always work with double precision". I of course agree that there are lots of cases where single precision is important (e.g., CUDA for speed). I've been using one of such CUDA packages, which is very fast :)

Comment: It is more of a slide rule reference. If you do not need the precision then doing it all in double precision, but only saving 4 significant digits means that you are wasting time. On a SIMD sense you are only 1/2 loading the register. Similarly when I have data that small I use byte, and generally C_INT32t, but sometimes I need INTEGER(KIND=8)... One may start out with double, but at some point care should be given to what the variables actually need to be.

Comment: Does this method of complex variable component calling: z%re, conform to the current Fortran standard?

Comment: @King, `z%re` and `z%im` are standard _complex part designators_, from F2008.