# How to plot the real and imaginary parts of an array?

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I've written a program that calculates the Discrete Fourier Transform of a sample, where in this case I'm sampling a sine wave. To test it, I need to plot the result. However, the resultant array is filled with complex values.

So how do I extract the real and imaginary components of these array elements, and then plot them against their indexes?

Here's my code:

```
program DFT
implicit none
integer :: k, N, x, y, j, r, l, istat
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
real, allocatable,dimension(:) :: h
complex, allocatable, dimension(:) :: rst
complex, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: W
real(kind=dp) :: pi, z, P, A, i
pi = 3.14159265359
P = 2*pi
A = 1
!open file to write results to
open(unit=100, file="dft.dat", status='replace')

N = 10
!allocate arrays as length N, apart from W (NxN)


allocate(h(N))
allocate(rst(N))
allocate(W(-N/2:N/2,1:N))

pi = 3.14159265359
!loop to fill the sample containing array
do k=1,N
  h(k) = sin((2*k*pi)/N)
end do

!loop to fill the product matrix with values
do j = -N/2,N/2
do k = 1, N

    W(j,k) = EXP((2.0_dp*pi*cmplx(0.0_dp,1.0_dp)*j*k)/N)

end do
end do
!use of matmul command to multiply matrices
rst = matmul(W,h)
!print *, h, w


write(100,*) rst

end program
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic and specific functions to get real and imaginary parts of complex variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818050/generic-and-specific-functions-to-get-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-complex-variab)

Comment: Please fix your kinds - they are not a meaningless decoration, they are fundamental to the accuracy of your calculation

Answer (score 2):

The REAL  intrinsic function returns the real part of a complex number in Fortran. It is an elemental function as well, so for an array of type complex simply  REAL( array ) will return a real array with the same kind as the original containing the results you want.

The AIMAG intrinsic function returns the imaginary part of a complex number in Fortran. It is an elemental function as well, so for an array of type complex simply AIMAG( array ) will return a real array with the same kind as the original containing the results you want.

Alternatively in Fortran 2003 latter %re and %im can be used to access the real and imaginary part respectively of a complex variable. The comments about their elemental nature again apply.

These are easily found by googling, or better I think every Fortran programmer should at least have access to a copy of Metcalf, Reid and Cohen "Modern Fortran Explained".

Comment: `%re` and `%im` is still not supported in gfortran